# Listview on a button click

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-button

I am making an Android App on Android Studio where I will have a set of buttons. Say I have 2 buttons, Cricket and Football. So when I click on Cricket it will go to another activity and show a listView with some items say name of cricketers. On clicking football it will show another listView with name of footballers. There will be multiple data on each item of ListView. How can this be done?

Can I do it on a single activity which is separate from main_activity?

Comment: yes you can do on a single activity

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can use [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) to do that. Bytheway, be sure to read the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking a question. For instance, your question doesn't include your current effort.

Answer (score 0):

try this
pass field as cricket or football in intent and in next activity checks that field is either cricket or football and basis on that field pass corresponding list data in list view.